# Jasperreports OSGI (fuse/karaf)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, osgi, jbossfuse, karaf

Been trying to use Jaspereports in an OSGI (Jboss Fuse/Karaf) environment.

I can't find the OSGI artifacts for jaspereports 6.3.0.
When i try to wrap the jar, I get errors from the non-OSGI dependencies such as itext.

Is there a way to use this in an OSGI environment?

Answer (score 0):

I've packaged to an OSGi bunlde, you can find here:

https://github.com/liveSense/org.liveSense.framework.jasperreports

It is an old version (4.5.0), but worked, I've used for production system.

The updated version of pom.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.github.livesense</groupId>
<artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
<version>6.3.0</version>

<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>liveSense :: Framework :: Jasper reports</name>
<description>
    liveSense Jasper report framework
</description>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <_exportcontents>
                        net.sf.jasperreports.*;version=6.3.0
                    </_exportcontents>
                    <Import-Package>
                        com.apple.mrj.*;resolution:=optional,
                        com.lowagie.toolbox.*;resolution:=optional,
                        javax.mail.*;resolution:=optional,
                        junit.*;resolution:=optional,
                        antlr.*;resolution:=optional,
                        bsh.*;resolution:=optional,
                        jxl.*;resolution:=optional,
                        mondrian.*;resolution:=optional,
                        net.sourceforge.barbecue.*;resolution:=optional,
                        com.adobe.xmp.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.batik.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.poi.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.lucene.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.tools.ant.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.velocity.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.codehaus.jackson.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.eclipse.jdt.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.exolab.castor.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.hibernate.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.jaxen.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.krysalis.barcode4j.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.springframework.beans.factory.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.springframework.core.io.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.w3c.dom.svg.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.apache.commons.javaflow.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.mozilla.javascript.*;resolution:=optional,
                        com.google.zxing.*;resolution:=optional,
                        org.olap4j.*;resolution:=optional,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>


                    <!-- bundle supplied resource prefixes -->
                    <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>

                    <!-- Do not inline jars, include as jar files -->
                    <!-- There are config files with same name will be overwritten -->
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>


                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>

    <!-- Embedded dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.23</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And to deploy I've used the folowing bundles (in karaf 4.0.1) - I think not all of that required in fuse, because installed features contains some of these bundles.

```
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-io/commons-io/1.4
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.6
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-dbutils/commons-dbutils/1.3
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-codec/1.3_2
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-math/2.2
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4
bundle:install -s mvn:commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.2
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient/3.1_6
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.4.5
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.1
bundle:install -s mvn:org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46
bundle:install -s mvn:org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk16/1.46
bundle:install -s mvn:org.bouncycastle/bctsp-jdk16/1.46
bundle:install -s mvn:org.bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk16/1.46
bundle:install -s mvn:org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/1.8.2
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xalan/2.7.1_6
bundle:install -s mvn:com.ibm.icu/icu4j/49.1
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.bcel/5.2_4
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xalan/2.7.1_4
```